# OTA deploy with certificate error for iOS8

Tags: ios, ssl, ios8, ota

I have a certificate problem when install app with OTA deployment site in intranet.

The OTA site is not SSL, it works fine with iOS 6.x, but it just failed to install in iOS 8 with certificate problem.

We don't use MDM for deployment and I have tried to use self-signed certificate to build a SSL OTA site, but it still failed.

I want to ask if there is any advise to fix this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a real SSL certificate with new iOS versions. Using self-made certificate might work if you install it on the devices, but I haven't tried this.

Note that the actual ipa doesn't have to be on a SSL secured site, only the plist file. And you could use 3rd party file storing services to host that file and have the ipa on another server.